# Hard drive indicator is slightly flashing all the time

Tags: hard-drive, indicator, disk

My laptop's hard drive indicator is slightly flashing, even when idle.

How do I figure out which process is causing the hard drive activity and stop it? I believe there shouldn't be any hard drive activity that goes on all the time.

My laptop is Lenovo ThinkPad X200 with 8GB of RAM, most of which is unused. Hard drive is Intel 520 120GB. Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

**Update**: so, using `iotop`, I have caught `chrome`, `firefox` and `jbd2/sda3-8` at disk writes. What can I do now and what is this `jbd2/sda3-8` thing?

[image: iotop results 1]
[image: iotop results 2]

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/141075/169736

Comment: your hard disk is always going to be getting hit a little bit - stuff writing to log files, temp data being flushed to disk etc.

Comment: I don't believe there's valid reason to write log files every second or two. There should be no reason to swap either, when the system is idle and less than half of RAM is utilized.

Answer (score 2):

`iotop` is useful for listing the processes disk usage

Comment: Note that `iotop` must typically be run as root to work: `sudo iotop`

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I can do now? I have updated the question.