# 14.04 - jbd2 and kworker constantly writing to disk

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive

jbd2 and kworker are writing to the disk every few seconds. Although there are a lot of questions related to this topic (as for example [12.04 Excessive hard disk activity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141075/excessive-hard-disk-activity)), I could not solve it. My disk is running for a couple of months, so it should have finished indexing. I do not see any frequent additions in the log files. The disk seems to be in order according to the disk utility. The hard disk also passed a forced check of partition. fsck of the partition revealed that it is mounted, but e2fsck could not continue.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

kworker is no big deal, jbd2 might be a debug log running (some app is set to debug), jbd2 may be MB size writes. kworker stands for "kernel worker", but again it is generally very minimal activity. I am trying to find out why jbd2 is constantly writing to all my disks every few seconds. Some say to change the "commits" in fstab to 60s, (default for ext4 is 5s). Here's an article regarding noatime vs relatime (and norelatime) for editing fstab:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/Relatime.html