# high disk io usage of jbd2-sda and mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mysql, gparted, disk-usage

Problem:

I always boot my computer to open Ubuntu 18.04LTS or Windows 10. Ubuntu has high disk io with jbd2/sda8-8 and mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid and their io increasing simultaneously. I checked with iotop.

Possible Cause 1:

There was an unallocated space for a long time (more than 1 year). I allocated 150gb unallocated memory with Windows. Then Gparted has a warning at /dev/sda3 (size128mb) which is Microsoft Reserved Partition and it is written that

```
Warning: Unable to detect file system Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sda3 is missing
```

Was there any data loss during disk partitioning? or How can I understand if there is?

Possible Cause 2:

I was working on a data warehouse project(approximately 500mb) but my computer froze while loading data to mysql. When I filtered mysql with htop I realised more than 25 mysql commands there and somethimes 2 or 3 of them changing their status from S to D. (D status means [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16740/366863))
How can I solve the io issue?

Possible Solution:

I am not sure but I run the fist commend in [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/284582/959041) and I realised that the log size is increasing sharply. So maybe it is the hit for solution.

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  15232712 Ağu 14 16:50 /var/log/kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   4925322 Ağu 14 16:50 /var/log/syslog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   450367 Ağu 14 15:49 /var/log/boot.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   utmp   292292 Tem 17 23:50 /var/log/lastlog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     80317 Ağu 14 16:17 /var/log/auth.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    67608 Ağu 14 15:30 /var/log/dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    57457 Tem 19  2016 /var/log/bootstrap.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    48688 Ağu 14 15:51 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    34811 Haz 30  2018 /var/log/Xorg.1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    32032 Tem 17 23:50 /var/log/faillog
```

Can you help me anyway?